# Test failing in React Testing Library / Jest despite correct DOM behavior

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm pretty new to Jest and testing, so I'm making an app using React, React Testing Library, and Jest to improve my skills.

One of my tests is failing, and I can't figure out why. Here is the code from my test:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
// using UrlShortener since the state has been lifted up for UrlList
import UrlShortener from '../../pages/UrlShortener/UrlShortener'

...

    test('URL list displays valid URL from input bar', async () => {
        const passingText = 'http://www.google.com';
        const testText = 'test4';
        render(<UrlShortener />);
        const urlInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter URL here...');
        const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name your URL...');
        const submitBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Shorten!' });
        userEvent.type(urlInput, passingText);
        userEvent.type(nameInput, testText);
        userEvent.click(submitBtn);
        const listButton = screen.getByText('Link History');
        userEvent.click(listButton);
        const list = await screen.findAllByText(/visits/i);
        await waitFor(() => expect(list).toHaveLength(4));
    });
```

The thing that's confusing me is that I can see that the list is 4 elements long in the log from the failing test, but for some reason it's not getting picked up in the expect() function. Here's what the log is giving me (it clearly shows 4 elements in the list):

```
    expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

    Expected length: 4
    Received length: 3
    Received array:  [<p>Visits: 2</p>, <p>Visits: 1</p>, <p>Visits: 5</p>]

...

<div>
    <div
    class="sc-iqHYmW gBcZyO"
    >
    <p>
      <a
        href="http://www.baseUrl.com/123"
      >
        test1
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      Visits: 
      2
    </p>
    </div>
    <div
    class="sc-iqHYmW gBcZyO"
    >
    <p>
      <a
        href="http://www.baseUrl.com/456"
      >
        test2
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      Visits: 
      1
    </p>
    </div>
    <div
    class="sc-iqHYmW gBcZyO"
    >
    <p>
      <a
        href="http://www.baseUrl.com/789"
      >
        test3
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      Visits: 
      5
    </p>
    </div>
    <div
    class="sc-iqHYmW gBcZyO"
    >
    <p>
      <a
        href="http://www.baseUrl.com/shorten/123"
      >
        test4
      </a>
    </p>
    <p>
      Visits: 
      9
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How is it possible that the DOM is behaving as expected in the log, but is failing in the actual test?

**Update:**

I'm adding more information so it's obvious what I'm doing. Basically, I've lifted state up from a child component (`UrlList`) to the parent (`UrlShortener`) so that I could pass a state updater function down to a sibling (`UrlBar`). The UrlShortener makes an axios call to the backend, then passes down a list of URLs to the `UrlList` component. When you click the submit button in the `UrlBar` component, it re-runs the axios call and updates the list with the new URL added.

**Parent component:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SectionPage, BackButton, PageTitle } from './style';
import axios from 'axios';
import UrlBar from '../../components/UrlBar/UrlBar';
import UrlList from '../../components/UrlList/UrlList';
import { Url } from '../../types/types';

const UrlShortener = () => {
    const [urls, setUrls] = useState<Url[] | []>([]);

    const getUrls = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://fullstack-demos.herokuapp.com/shorten/urls/all')
            .then((res) => setUrls(res.data));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getUrls();
    }, []);

    return (
        <SectionPage>
            <BackButton href='/'>Go Back</BackButton>
            <PageTitle>URL Shortener</PageTitle>
            <UrlBar getUrls={getUrls} />
            <UrlList urls={urls} />
        </SectionPage>
    );
};

export default UrlShortener;
```

**Children:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    ComponentWrapper,
    Subtitle,
    Triangle,
    LinksContainer,
    LinkGroup,
} from './style';
import { Url } from '../../types/types';

interface IProps {
    urls: Url[] | [];
}

const UrlList: React.FC<IProps> = ({ urls }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
    };

    return (
        <ComponentWrapper>
            <Subtitle onClick={handleClick}>
                Link History <Triangle>{open ? '▼' : '▲'}</Triangle>
            </Subtitle>
            <LinksContainer>
                <div>
                    {open &&
                        urls.map(({ urlId, shortUrl, urlName, visits }: Url) => (
                            <LinkGroup key={urlId}>
                                <p>
                                    <a href={shortUrl}>{urlName}</a>
                                </p>
                                <p>Visits: {visits}</p>
                            </LinkGroup>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </LinksContainer>
        </ComponentWrapper>
    );
};

export default UrlList;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { UrlInput, NameInput, UrlButton } from './style';
import { validateUrl } from '../../utils/utils';

interface IProps {
    getUrls: () => void;
}

const UrlBar: React.FC<IProps> = ({ getUrls }) => {
    const [urlInput, setUrlInput] = useState('');
    const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean | string>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Cleanup fixes React testing error: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"
        return () => {
            setUrlInput('');
        };
    }, []);

    const handleUrlChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setUrlInput(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setNameInput(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!nameInput) {
            setError('Please name your URL');
        } else if (!validateUrl(urlInput)) {
            setError('Invalid Input');
        } else {
            setError(false);
            await axios.post('https://fullstack-demos.herokuapp.com/shorten', {
                longUrl: urlInput,
                urlName: nameInput,
            });
            setUrlInput('');
            setNameInput('');
            getUrls();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <NameInput
                    type='text'
                    name='nameInput'
                    id='nameInput'
                    placeholder='Name your URL...'
                    maxLength={20}
                    onChange={handleNameChange}
                    value={nameInput}
                />
                <UrlInput
                    type='text'
                    name='urlInput'
                    id='urlInput'
                    placeholder='Enter URL here...'
                    onChange={handleUrlChange}
                    value={urlInput}
                />
                <UrlButton name='button' type='submit'>
                    Shorten!
                </UrlButton>
                {error && <label htmlFor='urlInput'>{error}</label>}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UrlBar;
```

Comment: What happens on click? What is UrlShortener doing? You may need to await an async act or be updating state that needs to be wrapped in act.

Comment: @Morgan, just updated the thread to answer your question. Hopefully that makes it more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You should really be mocking your axios calls. You also are updating state when mounting UrlShortener inside the useEffect. I would wrap your render in an await act async as well as wrap the click events with act. https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act

Comment: @Morgan, I'm actually using Mock Service Worker to mock the axios calls: https://mswjs.io/ . I will try the act() solution, although the docs you provided say that `testing library` (which I'm using) helpers are already wrapped in act().

Comment: Did your figure this out?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac nope...wrapping in act() didn't do anything. I asked in a few other places as well and never got a solution. I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0):

So after fighting to get my tests to pass for another component, I finally figured out how to get this one to pass. Apparently I just needed to add a few more waitFor() and await statements to catch some of the async stuff happening in my component. I'd be lying if I said I understand why this fixes my problem, but now I know that if my tests are failing even though I can see the right results in the JEST DOM, it probably has to do with missing waitFor / awaits.

```
    test('URL list displays valid URL from input bar', async () => {
        const passingText = 'http://www.google.com';
        const testText = 'test4';
        render(<UrlShortener />);
        const urlInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter URL here...');
        const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name your URL...');
        const submitBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Shorten!' });
        userEvent.type(urlInput, passingText);
        userEvent.type(nameInput, testText);
        await waitFor(() => userEvent.click(submitBtn));
        const listButton = await screen.findByText('Link History');
        await waitFor(() => userEvent.click(listButton));
        const list = await screen.findAllByText(/visits/i);
        await waitFor(() => expect(list).toHaveLength(4));
    });
});
```